# PHP spl_autoload_register not working with use funciton import

Tags: php, autoload, spl-autoload-register

When using spl_autoload_register, an imported function via `use function Namespace\Subamespace\aFunc` php cannot find the function. The registered autolaod function is not invoked. If I manually `include Path/To/File.php` then the use statement works and the included function will work. Solutions?

autoload.php

```
function loader($class){
  printf("in loader");
  /*code to load file*/
}

spl_autoload_register('loader');
```

index.php

```
include_once('autoload.php');

use function Namespace\Subnamespace\aFunc;

$output = aFunc();
```

Namespace/Subnamespace.php

```
<?php namespace Namespace\Subnamespace;

function aFunc() {
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use function doesn't import functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51547511/use-function-doesnt-import-functions-in-php)

Comment: I understand use doesn't import functions but I don't understand why my autoload function in autoload.php,using spl_autoload_register(), isn't been called even though I'm referencing the namespace and calling the function.

Comment: If you hunt around you will find that it does not work on functions. It only works for classes. So you will still have to include your function files. A workaround is to put your functions in a class and make them static (i.e. a singleton) and call them class::method.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw yes that appears to be the case; autoloading only works with classes, traits, interfaces. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Autoloader for functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737199/autoloader-for-functions)